# How to upload a file to Amazon Glacier Deep Archive using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've managed to upload a file to Glacier, but I want to upload to Deep Archive directly. I've searched the documentation, but found no mentions of how to set the storage class to `DEEP_ARCHIVE` directly.

Comment: Are you wanting to upload to the Amazon Glacier service, or do you wish to upload to Amazon S3 and set the storage class? (I know, it's confusing terminology.)

Comment: I want to directoy upload archives to Amazon Glacier Deep Archive. No S3 involved.

Comment: This is not possible. "Glacier Deep Archive" is a storage class of Amazon S3. It is not available directly from Glacier. If you create an Archive in Glacier, it is simply charged at the standard Glacier storage price (currently in US `$0.004 per GB / Month`).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I was still confused about Deep Archive not being available through Glacier.

Comment: As s3 glacier & glacier deep archive being integrated with S3 might be the reason. You can check this https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/getting-started-using-amazon-s3-glacier-and-s3-glacier-deep-archive/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use `put_object()`, which has a `StorageClass` parameter, or you can use `upload_file()` while specifying `ExtraArgs`:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'my-bucket', 'hello.txt', ExtraArgs={'StorageClass': 'DEEP_ARCHIVE'})
```

Permitted `ExtraArgs` can be found at [ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer.ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS).

To clarify: This is **uploading to Amazon S3** but setting the Storage Class to *Glacier Deep Archive*. This is different to uploading to the Amazon Glacier service. (These days it is easier to use Glacier via S3 storage classes).

Comment: Glacier has no such thing as a Key (object name). You upload a file, and get a response containing the ArchiveID. What am I supposed to set as the Key (third parameter) in the `upload_file` call? I've tried None, but it fails with `missing required positional argument`.

Comment: What is the actual difference between
1 "uploading to Amazon S3 but setting the Storage Class to Glacier Deep Archive"
and
2 "uploading to the Amazon Glacier service"?

so, option 1 you can see it on the S3 file browser? and what happens when you click download? 
are you charged the same storage and retrieval fees with both options 1 and 2?

thank you.

Comment: (2) In s3 glacier you can not upload object of glacier deep archive storage class. And you can not download glacier or deep archive data before restoring it first. All storage and retrieval prices are same I think but, S3 glacier might have some additional retrieval policies. You can check here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/data-retrieval-policy.html

Comment: **Amazon Glacier is different to S3 Storage Classes that use 'Glacier'.** The 'original' Amazon Glacier service uses Vaults, and Archives. It is a real pain to use. To make things easier, Amazon S3 now has a **Glacier Storage Class** that makes it easy to use Glacier directly from S3. It is also **cheaper than using the Glacier service**. These days, you should only use the Glacier storage classes in S3, rather than using the Amazon Glacier service itself.