# How to download archive from Glacier Deep Archive locally using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-glacier

I uploaded zip file on Glacier Deep Archive. Now I want to download the same file locally with boto3 library. What is the way to do it? I tried to find any example, but failed. I have `vault_name` and `archive_id` saved. It is less than 1GB in weight. How long does it take to download such a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can actually download the object, in boto3 you have to execute [restore_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.restore_object) operation. Once the object is restored, you can then download it from S3. From [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.restore_object):

> Objects in the GLACIER and DEEP_ARCHIVE storage classes are **archived**. To access an archived object, you must first **initiate a restore request**. This restores a temporary copy of the archived object.

Comment: On that link it is written "Restores an archived copy of an object back into Amazon S3", but I don't want to restore it on S3.I want to download it locally.

Comment: The thing is that I uploaded zip file from my hard disk to Glacier Deep Archive. I didn't use S3 at all. Now, how can I return it back on hard disk? Any restore object should have memory where it was on S3 previously, right? But it wasn't on S3 at all. It was locally on my hard disk.

Comment: @Alem `Glacier Deep Archive` is a storage class in S3. Can you go to S3 console and check there. You should be able to verify its storage class.

Comment: I really don't understand. I know that Glacier Deep Archive is a storage class in S3 when I change some object on S3 to be on Glacier Deep Archive storage. I understand that. But this file wasn't on S3 at all. I don't want it to be in some bucket. I want to download it locally with only vault_name and archive_id informations without using S3 buckets.

Comment: I want to do something like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/getting-started-download-archive-java.html but with python

Comment: @Alem The link is for Glacier, not deep archive. So where exactly did you upload your objects and how?

Comment: I uploaded it with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-glacier-upload_archive.py.html

Comment: @Alem Your link says "Amazon S3 Glacier vault", but your question title and body of the question is about Deep Archive. These are totally two different storage systems. Please edit your question to correctly reflect what you did, other wise its only confusing.

Comment: It seems that I just missed the way how to upload on Glacier Deep Archive. The question is ok, but it seems like I missed the point of difference between Glacier and Glacier Deep Archive, so I used wrong function to upload. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039076/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-glacier-deep-archive-using-boto3 for upload on Deep Archive. Thank you very much for your answers. You really helped me a lot.

Comment: @Alem No problem. Glad I could clarify the issue.